# When I need to install (bench) given file missing Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, erpnext, frappe

Hello Friends When I need to install bench after get repo from GitHub Given to me that setup.py not found.When I compare between all file I didn't find it on original repo

```
pip install -e ./bench
```

**This Error**

```
Directory './bench' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

**I need to know, Why is this happen?**

Comment: Is there a file called `setup.py` inside the directory `bench`?

Comment: No file called that

Comment: That's the problem. You can only use `pip install` with directories which contain a correctly written `setup.py` file.

Comment: What should I do to solve this problem this command writen in documentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the pip command you use is for Python 2, or outdated.

Try invoking pip via the target python interpreter directly (like `python3.x -m pip`). You may also want to make sure pip is up to date prior to that:

```bash
python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install -e ./bench
```